# Is there a way to read a word document section by section with c#

Tags: c#-4.0, openxml, office-interop

I have a word template which has multiple sections( tables, parragraphs, lists, etc.. ). The idea is that users fill the template and upload it to a asp.net application. I need the application to read the information section by section. So,  is there a way to name the section of a word document and identify it by using c#?

Comment: For starters: The term `Section` is Word is a very specific thing, defined by a "section break" and used to enable different page orientations, different headers/footers, restarting page numbering, etc. Please only use "section" when discussing a problem with Word when that is *exactly* what you mean. It's confusing, otherwise, and makes what you ask unclear. Look at the concepts: 1) Bookmarks; 2) Content Controls. The latter will be simpler to work with in Office Open XML documents.

Answer (score -1):

I think it is much better to create a custom web page for filling fields there and constructing a Word document on the server-side using the Open XML SDK, see [Welcome to the Open XML SDK 2.5 for Office](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/open-xml-sdk) for more information.

However, you may consider using bookmarks or content controls as a marker for sections.

Otherwise, you'll need to parse the uploaded document by searching for keywords presented in the template.